# Error en PHP-MySQL: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given

Tags: php, mysqli

Escribo porque me estoy volviendo loco con este error.

Me sale este error
"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given"

Con este código

```
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'random_name_of_db');
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");

    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        echo "Fallo ".$conexion->connect_error;
        exit();
    }

 if(isset($_GET['a'])){
        $query = "select * from accesorios where nombre = '".str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['a'])."'";
    }else if(isset($_GET['j'])){
        $query = "select * from juguetes where nombre = '".str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['j'])."'";
    }

    if($consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $query)){
        while($juguete = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
            $precio = $juguete['precio'];
            $fotos = explode(',', $juguete['fotos']);
            $moneda = '';
            include 'pais.php';
            echo "<table>
                  .......
                  </table>";
        }
     }
```

Lo que es más raro es que realiza la consulta y muestra los resultados correctamente, pero con el cuadro del error detrás de la tabla.
No consigo ver el error (el warning dice que está en la línea del while), a ver si me podéis ayudar entre todos.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

¡Ya he encontrado el fallo! Resulta que existe otra variable $consulta en otro archivo php que está incluido en este php y esa $consulta es un array. Por eso la mysqli me devolvía que estaba encontrando un array donde debería encontrar una mysqli_connect.

Este el código que funciona producto.php:

```
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'juguetesparamismascotas');
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");

    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        echo "Fallo ".$conexion->connect_error;
        exit();
    }

    include 'pais.php';

    if(isset($_GET['a'])){
        $query = "select * from accesorios where nombre = '".str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['a'])."'";
    }

    if(isset($_GET['j'])){
        $query = "select * from juguetes where nombre = '".str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['j'])."'";
    }

    if($consult = mysqli_query($conexion,$query)){
        while($juguete = mysqli_fetch_array($consult)){
            $precio = $juguete['precio'];
            $fotos = explode(',', $juguete['fotos']);
            $moneda = '';
            include 'pais.php';  // <- Aquí se confunde la $consulta

        echo"<table>......</table>";
```

Y este es el otro archivo culpable del error pais.php:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$consulta = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip.''));

$pais = $consulta['geoplugin_countryName'];

$euro = array('Austria', 'Belgium', 'Cyprus', 'Greece', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Portugal', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Andorra', 'Montenegro', 'San Marino');
if(in_array($pais, $euro)){
    $precio = $precio*1.00;
    $moneda = "€";
}
```

Comment: Solo diré... plop. jajaja

Comment: Cómo para encontrarlo... Lo que me ha costado xD